# Create Role assignment dynamically in Terraform from input

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform0.12+

I am trying to create multiple role assignments using a typical variable given below where "permission {}" is a new variable I would like to introduce in the form of a type map, so I can perform multiple role assignments.

My TFVARS file

```
azure_vnets= {
  prod= [
    {
      cidr = ["10.0.0.0/24"]
      vnet_name = "vnet1"
      dns  = ["10.0.0.1"]
      rg   = "myrg1"
      permission = {
      Contributor =  ["xxxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"],
      Reader = ["xxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxx"]
      } 
      location = "eastus"
    },
    {
      cidr = ["10.0.1.0/24"]
      vnet_name = "vnet2"
      dns  = ["10.0.1.2"]
      rg   = "myrg2"
      permission = {
      Contributor =  ["xxxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"],
      Reader = ["xxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxx"]
      } 
      location = "westeurope"
    }
  ],
  nonprod = [
     {
      cidr = ["10.0.3.0/24"]
      vnet_name = "vnet1"
      dns  = ["10.0.3.1"]
      rg   = "nonprodrg"
      location = "eastus"
      permission = {
      Contributor =  ["xxxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"],
      Reader = ["xxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxx"]
      } 
    },
    {
      cidr = ["10.0.4.0/24"]
      vnet_name = "nonprod-vnet2"
      dns  = ["10.0.4.2"]
      sub  = "nonProd"
      rg   = "mynonprodrg"
      permission = {
      Contributor =  ["xxxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"],
      Reader = ["xxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxx"]
      } 
      location = "westeurope"
    }
  ]
}
```

**My resource creation file**
I have a local defined here which helps me use the above variable in a for_each loop given below in the role assignment creation. I would like to know how to get the Rolename as Key and ObjectID as value in the below for_each role_assignment creation from the above TFvar variable

```
locals {
  flat_azure_vnets = merge([
      for env_name, env_vn_list in var.azure_vnets:
         {
           for idx, env_vn in env_vn_list:
             "${env_name}-${idx}" => env_vn
         }
    ]...)
}


resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "role_assignment" {
    for_each = { for k, v in local.flat_azure_vnets  : k => v }
    scope                = azurerm_resource_group.this.id
    role_definition_name = each.xxx
    principal_id         = each.key
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with the current code? Any errors?

Comment: Hi @Marcin I have not tested as I am not sure how to grab for example Contributor as role_definition for each iteration and its object ids as principal_id. I am not sure how to implement this and not sure if we can do this in just one resource block or if it is required to have two such blocks say one for Contributor and another for Reader. That is also fine for me. Thanks for looking into as always

Comment: because here I have now introduced a new variable permission which is again a map.

Comment: If you want to iterate over `permission`, you have to further flatten your `flat_azure_vnets`, as not it not flat.

Answer (score 1):

To iterate over your new `permission` attribute, you have to further flatten your `flat_azure_vnets`. So you can introduce `flat_azure_vnets2`:

```
locals {
  flat_azure_vnets = merge([
      for env_name, env_vn_list in var.azure_vnets:
         {
           for idx, env_vn in env_vn_list:
             "${env_name}-${idx}" => env_vn
         }
    ]...)
    

  flat_azure_vnets2 = merge([
      for key, env in local.flat_azure_vnets:
         {
           for cidx, contrinutor in env["permission"]["Contributor"]:
             "${key}-${cidx}" => merge(
                   env, {
                       "contrinutor" = contrinutor,
                       "reader" = env["permission"]["Reader"][cidx]
                       }
               )
         }
    ]...)
}
```

which produces `flat_azure_vnets2` in the form of (notice new `contrinutor` and `reader` attributes):

```
test = {
  "nonprod-0-0" = {
    "cidr" = [
      "10.0.3.0/24",
    ]
    "contrinutor" = "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
    "dns" = [
      "10.0.3.1",
    ]
    "location" = "eastus"
    "permission" = {
      "Contributor" = [
        "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      ]
      "Reader" = [
        "xxxxxxxxxxx",
        "xxxxxxxxxx",
      ]
    }
    "reader" = "xxxxxxxxxxx"
    "rg" = "nonprodrg"
    "vnet_name" = "vnet1"
  }
  "nonprod-0-1" = {
    "cidr" = [
      "10.0.3.0/24",
    ]
    "contrinutor" = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    "dns" = [
      "10.0.3.1",
    ]
    "location" = "eastus"
    "permission" = {
      "Contributor" = [
        "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      ]
      "Reader" = [
        "xxxxxxxxxxx",
        "xxxxxxxxxx",
      ]
    }
    "reader" = "xxxxxxxxxx"
    "rg" = "nonprodrg"
    "vnet_name" = "vnet1"
  }
  "nonprod-1-0" = {
    "cidr" = [
      "10.0.4.0/24",
    ]
    "contrinutor" = "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
    "dns" = [
      "10.0.4.2",
    ]
    "location" = "westeurope"
    "permission" = {
      "Contributor" = [
        "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      ]
      "Reader" = [
        "xxxxxxxxxxx",
        "xxxxxxxxxx",
      ]
    }
    "reader" = "xxxxxxxxxxx"
    "rg" = "mynonprodrg"
    "sub" = "nonProd"
    "vnet_name" = "nonprod-vnet2"
  }
  "nonprod-1-1" = {
    "cidr" = [
      "10.0.4.0/24",
    ]
    "contrinutor" = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    "dns" = [
      "10.0.4.2",
    ]
    "location" = "westeurope"
    "permission" = {
      "Contributor" = [
        "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      ]
      "Reader" = [
        "xxxxxxxxxxx",
        "xxxxxxxxxx",
      ]
    }
    "reader" = "xxxxxxxxxx"
    "rg" = "mynonprodrg"
    "sub" = "nonProd"
    "vnet_name" = "nonprod-vnet2"
  }
  "prod-0-0" = {
    "cidr" = [
      "10.0.0.0/24",
    ]
    "contrinutor" = "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
    "dns" = [
      "10.0.0.1",
    ]
    "location" = "eastus"
    "permission" = {
      "Contributor" = [
        "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      ]
      "Reader" = [
        "xxxxxxxxxxx",
        "xxxxxxxxxx",
      ]
    }
    "reader" = "xxxxxxxxxxx"
    "rg" = "myrg1"
    "vnet_name" = "vnet1"
  }
  "prod-0-1" = {
    "cidr" = [
      "10.0.0.0/24",
    ]
    "contrinutor" = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    "dns" = [
      "10.0.0.1",
    ]
    "location" = "eastus"
    "permission" = {
      "Contributor" = [
        "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      ]
      "Reader" = [
        "xxxxxxxxxxx",
        "xxxxxxxxxx",
      ]
    }
    "reader" = "xxxxxxxxxx"
    "rg" = "myrg1"
    "vnet_name" = "vnet1"
  }
  "prod-1-0" = {
    "cidr" = [
      "10.0.1.0/24",
    ]
    "contrinutor" = "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
    "dns" = [
      "10.0.1.2",
    ]
    "location" = "westeurope"
    "permission" = {
      "Contributor" = [
        "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      ]
      "Reader" = [
        "xxxxxxxxxxx",
        "xxxxxxxxxx",
      ]
    }
    "reader" = "xxxxxxxxxxx"
    "rg" = "myrg2"
    "vnet_name" = "vnet2"
  }
  "prod-1-1" = {
    "cidr" = [
      "10.0.1.0/24",
    ]
    "contrinutor" = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    "dns" = [
      "10.0.1.2",
    ]
    "location" = "westeurope"
    "permission" = {
      "Contributor" = [
        "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      ]
      "Reader" = [
        "xxxxxxxxxxx",
        "xxxxxxxxxx",
      ]
    }
    "reader" = "xxxxxxxxxx"
    "rg" = "myrg2"
    "vnet_name" = "vnet2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Marcin I will try and get back. Much thanks

Comment: Hi @marcin Can you please also drop an example how I would use this in below code?

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "role_assignment" {
    for_each = local.flat_azure_vnets2 
    
    scope                = var.rg
    role_definition_name =
    principal_id         = each.key
}

Comment: Sorry for the dump question but I actually could not find way how to apply this

Answer (score 1):

**You can use the below example which I have tested in my environment:**

```
provider "azurerm"{
    features{}
}
locals {
  flat_azure_vnets = merge([
      for env_name, env_vn_list in var.azure_vnets:
         {
           for idx, env_vn in env_vn_list:
             "${env_name}-${idx}" => env_vn
         }
    ]...)
    flat_rbac = {for i,r in local.flat_azure_vnets : "role-${i}"=>"${r.permission}"}

    
}

variable "azure_vnets" {}

output "rbac" {
  value = local.flat_rbac
}
module "Contributor_roleAssignment" {
  for_each = zipmap(keys(local.flat_rbac), values(local.flat_rbac)[*].Contributor)
  source   = "./modules/roleAssignment"

  role_definition_name = "Contributor"
  scope_id             = "/subscriptions/948d4068-cee2-492b-8f82-e00a844e059b/resourceGroups/ansumantest"
  principal_ids        = each.value
}

module "Reader_roleAssignment" {
  for_each = zipmap(keys(local.flat_rbac), values(local.flat_rbac)[*].Reader)
  source   = "./modules/roleAssignment"

  role_definition_name = "Reader"
  scope_id             = "/subscriptions/948d4068-cee2-492b-8f82-e00a844e059b/resourceGroups/ansumantest"
  principal_ids        = each.value
}
```

---

**Role assignment module i.e. "./modules/roleAssignment"**

`main.tf`

```
locals {
    principals = toset(var.principal_ids)
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "role_assignment" {
    for_each = local.principals
    
    scope                = var.scope_id
    role_definition_name = var.role_definition_name
    principal_id         = each.key
}
```

`variables.tf` :

```
variable "role_definition_name" {
    type        = any
    description = "The name of the Role to assign to the chosen Scope."
}

variable "scope_id" {
  type        = string
  description = "The Id of the scope where the role should be assigned."
}

variable "principal_ids" {
  type        = list(string)
  description = "The ID of the principal that is to be assigned the role at the given scope. Can be User, Group or SPN."
}
```

---

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you @Ansun I will try your solution as well. Many thanks