# Why does both custom role definition and role assignment needs scope?

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to create a role definition and assign it to aks user managed identity for the subnet join action (without which it fails to create pods in the subnet), i see it is asking for scope, in both the cases, i need to provide the scope of the subnet, and i have to repeat that for multiple subnet, in such case, what is the point of having too many definitions? can't we make it generic, here is the code that i am trying to do this.

```
# CREATING THE ROLE DEFINITION
resource "azurerm_role_definition" "aad_custom_rbac_k8s_ingress_snet_join_action" {
 name = "CustomRole K8s In Subnet Join Action"
 description = "Allows pods to be created in the specified subnet."
 scope = var.id_snet_k8s_ingress
 permissions {
 actions = [
 "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/join/action"
    ]
  }
}

# ASSIGING THE ROLE TO THE MANAGED IDENTITY
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "aad_custom_rbac_k8s_ingress_snet_join_action" {
 scope = var.id_snet_k8s_egress
 role_definition_name = "CustomRole K8s In Subnet Join Action ${var.environment}"
 principal_id = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.aks_user_assigned_identity.principal_id
 depends_on = [azurerm_role_definition.aad_custom_rbac_k8s_ingress_snet_join_action]
}
```

It could have been nicer to have this role generic so that i can use it for the other subnets, please let me know if that is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Check by adding the required subnets to which the role is to be assigned in assignable_scopes parameter.
The value for scope is automatically included in this list if no other values supplied.

and use locals to use each of those subnetIds in theform of resourceId.

Terraform code:

***Variables.tf:***

```
variable "subnet_address_prefixes" {
  type = list(string)
  default = [ 
"/subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/xx/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/kexamplenetwork/subnets/internal" ,
"/subscriptions/b83cxxx23f/resourceGroups/xx/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/kexamplenetwork/subnets/subnet2"]
}
```

***Main.tf***

```
terraform {
  backend "azurerm" {
    resource_group_name  = "rg"
    storage_account_name = "remotestatekavstr243"
    container_name       = "terraform"
    key                  = "terraform.tfstate"
  }
}


resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "kexamplenetwork"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "example" {
  name                 = "internal"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefixes     =["10.0.3.0/24"] //var.subnet_address_prefixes //["10.0.3.0/24", var.subnet_address_prefixes ]
}
resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet2" {
  name                 = "subnet2"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefixes     =["10.0.2.0/24"] //var.subnet_address_prefixes //["10.0.3.0/24", var.subnet_address_prefixes ]
}


resource "azurerm_user_assigned_identity" "example" {
 resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  name                = "userassgnid"
  
}


locals { 
  sub_ids = [for sub_id in var.subnet_address_prefixes : sub_id]
    }

   resource "azurerm_role_definition" "terraform_role" {
     name = "CustomRole sub Join Action"
 description = "Allows pods to be created in the specified subnet."
      scope       = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.id
     
       permissions {
 actions = [
 "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/join/action"
    ]
  }

      assignable_scopes = local.sub_ids

      depends_on = [ azurerm_virtual_network.example, azurerm_subnet.example ,azurerm_subnet.subnet2]
               
    }


resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "aad_custom_rbac_" {
 scope = data.azurerm_subscription.current.id
 role_definition_name = "CustomRole K8s In Subnet Join Action"
 principal_id = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.example.principal_id
 depends_on = [azurerm_role_definition.terraform_role]
}
```

> **Note:** Scope in custom role definitions and role assignments are different. In custom role definition scope is  where the role
> definition can be used, while the scope in the role assignment defines
> where the assigned role is applicable and what resources it can
> access.

[image]

References:

1. [azurerm_role_assignment | Resources | hashicorp/azurerm | Terraform Registry](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/role_assignment)
2. [azure - Create Role assignment dynamically in Terraform from input - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71197656/create-role-assignment-dynamically-in-terraform-from-input)